# ERROR: Allocate: can't check in named futex name = jack_sem.system err = Permission denied

Tags: ubuntu, jack

The jack audio server recently stopped working on my computer. I've searched online for about 2 hours now and I cannot find any solutions for the error I'm having. Here is the error log:

```
Fri Dec  9 19:33:09 2016: ------------------
Fri Dec  9 19:33:09 2016: Controller activated. Version 1.9.11 (unknown) built on Fri Dec  9 06:06:45 2016
Fri Dec  9 19:33:09 2016: Loading settings from "/home/sean/.config/jack/conf.xml" using expat_2.1.0 ...
Fri Dec  9 19:33:09 2016: setting parameter 'engine':'driver':'(null)' to value "alsa"
Fri Dec  9 19:33:09 2016: setting parameter 'engine':'realtime':'(null)' to value "true"
Fri Dec  9 19:33:09 2016: setting parameter 'engine':'verbose':'(null)' to value "false"
Fri Dec  9 19:33:09 2016: setting parameter 'engine':'client-timeout':'(null)' to value "500"
Fri Dec  9 19:33:09 2016: setting parameter 'drivers':'alsa':'device' to value "hw:USB"
Fri Dec  9 19:33:09 2016: setting parameter 'drivers':'alsa':'capture' to value "hw:USB"
Fri Dec  9 19:33:09 2016: setting parameter 'drivers':'alsa':'playback' to value "hw:USB"
Fri Dec  9 19:33:09 2016: setting parameter 'drivers':'alsa':'rate' to value "44100"
Fri Dec  9 19:33:09 2016: setting parameter 'drivers':'alsa':'period' to value "1024"
Fri Dec  9 19:33:09 2016: setting parameter 'drivers':'alsa':'nperiods' to value "2"
Fri Dec  9 19:33:09 2016: setting parameter 'drivers':'alsa':'hwmon' to value "false"
Fri Dec  9 19:33:09 2016: setting parameter 'drivers':'alsa':'hwmeter' to value "false"
Fri Dec  9 19:33:09 2016: setting parameter 'drivers':'alsa':'duplex' to value "true"
Fri Dec  9 19:33:09 2016: setting parameter 'drivers':'alsa':'softmode' to value "false"
Fri Dec  9 19:33:09 2016: setting parameter 'drivers':'alsa':'monitor' to value "false"
Fri Dec  9 19:33:09 2016: setting parameter 'drivers':'alsa':'dither' to value "n"
Fri Dec  9 19:33:09 2016: setting parameter 'drivers':'alsa':'inchannels' to value "2"
Fri Dec  9 19:33:09 2016: setting parameter 'drivers':'alsa':'outchannels' to value "2"
Fri Dec  9 19:33:09 2016: setting parameter 'drivers':'alsa':'shorts' to value "false"
Fri Dec  9 19:33:09 2016: Listening for D-Bus messages
Fri Dec  9 19:33:10 2016: Starting jack server...
Fri Dec  9 19:33:10 2016: JACK server starting in realtime mode with priority 10
Fri Dec  9 19:33:10 2016: self-connect-mode is "Don't restrict self connect requests"
Fri Dec  9 19:33:10 2016: ERROR: Allocate: can't check in named futex name = jack_sem.system err = Permission denied
Fri Dec  9 19:33:10 2016: ERROR: Cannot allocate synchro
Fri Dec  9 19:33:10 2016: ERROR: Cannot allocate internal client for driver
Fri Dec  9 19:33:10 2016: ERROR: Cannot initialize driver
Fri Dec  9 19:33:10 2016: ERROR: JackServer::Open failed with -1
Fri Dec  9 19:33:10 2016: ERROR: Failed to open server
```

Here is my `uname -a` output if that helps:

```
Linux Sean-Lappy 4.4.0-53-generic #74-Ubuntu SMP Fri Dec 2 15:59:10 UTC 2016 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
```

The only conflict I can think of is I recently installed [LMMS](https://lmms.io/) and removed a bunch of old kernels using `sudo apt-get autoremove`

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

---

#### UPDATE (12/14/2016):

I still have not found a solution to this issue. I dug around in the source for jack and pinpointed the error at line 114 or 124 of [JackLinuxFutex.cpp](https://github.com/falkTX/jack2/blob/6f2e7a083a591acca06eee6bc70947b438feed43/linux/JackLinuxFutex.cpp#L114)

Here is the full, verbose jack output: http://pastebin.com/1FbNwCJU

I also install jack from source to no avail.

If anyone knows a fix, that would be wonderful considering I cannot use any audio devices on my laptop at the moment.

Comment: Same thing happened here. Jack stopped working with pulseaudio suddenly. Probably an update that messed it up

Comment: I'm having the error: "ERROR: Allocate: can't check in named futex name = jack_sem.1000_default_Calf Compressor err = Resource temporarily unavailable", where 'Calf Compressor' is just any client that fills up the total number of allowed clients (apparently).  Is there a limit on the number of clients (or futexes)? If so, how can I increase that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have finally fixed the problem. Here's the steps I used:

1. Uninstall everything sound related

   `sudo apt-get purge jackd qjackctl cadence pulseaudio pulseaudio-module-jack alsa`
2. Restart
3. Reinstall everything except jack

   `sudo apt-get install alsa alsa-firmware-loaders alsa-tools alsa-tools-gui alsa-firmware alsa-utils pulseaudio pulseaudio-module-jack cadence`
4. Restart
5. Download and unzip jack source code

   `sudo apt-get install unzip`

   `wget https://github.com/jackaudio/jack2/archive/master.zip`

   `unzip master.zip`
6. Install dependencies

   `sudo apt-get install libasound2-dev`
7. Compile jack from source with `--alsa` flag

   `cd jack2-master`

   `./waf configure --alsa`

   `./waf build`

   `sudo ./waf install`

I have no idea if this was the best approach or if it will work on anyone else's machine but I can tell you that jack is now running successfully and I am listening to music again.